# Can template parameters match both types and templates seamlessly, perhaps as part of a variadic?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, auto, variadic

My code is storing some state using a static-type construct similar to the one in `Boost.PolyCollection`.

My problem is, I think, minimally illustrated by the code below. Basically I'm working with parameter packs and need a way to "instantiate" a given template by what's in the pack.

```
#include <unordered_map>

template<typename... Ts>
struct Pack
{
    /*
    instantiate a given template with passed types + the types in this Pack
        but passed Template may take non-type template parameters, what to do??
    */
    // template<template<typename...> class Template, typename... As> // error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class ... Ts> template<template<template<class ...> class Template, class ... As> template<class ... Ts> template<class ...> class Template, class ... As> using Inst = Template<As ..., Ts ...>'
    // using Inst = Template<As..., Ts...>;


    // this works for my case, but it's too specific and ugly -
        // am fixing the first of As to be a non-type 
    template<template<template<typename...> class, typename...> class Template, template<typename...> class A1, typename... As>
    using Inst = Template<A1, As..., Ts...>;
};

template<template<typename...> class Segment, typename Key, typename... Ts>
class AnyMap
{
};

int main()
{
    typedef Pack<int, char> ServicePack;
    typedef long Key;

    using ServiceMap = typename ServicePack::template Inst<AnyMap, std::unordered_map, Key>; // AnyMap with given segment type and key
}
```

I was hoping `auto...`, which I haven't used much, to come to the rescue, but it seems `auto` won't match template template params, it's only meant for a Value of inferred type.

Do you know of a simple way to achieve this?

(perhaps evidently, this is about c++17)

Comment: Can you please give a simple example to elaborate what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to instantiate `AnyMap` with `std::unordered_map`, `Key`, and the 2 types inside `ServicePack`. Do that generically for any `Pack`.

Comment: IIRC this sort of use case was brought up as a limitation when `auto` template parameters were being proposed.  There were some proposals at the time for a keyword that could mean "a type or an object" in a template parameter list, but none were implemented.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Actually having randomly mixed type-params and template-params is not a scenario I can think of (the example in my question doesn't require that degree of generality, the question was more for understanding). For my example I can simply "bind" the non-type template param ahead of the others, using an alias, then do the Pack thing.

Comment: Same issue to instantiate `std::array`. No ways currently to generically take template class, type or value as template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two related approaches.

First is boost hana style.  Turn everything into compile time values.  Templates?  A value.  Types?  A value.  Values?  An instance of a type like integral constant.

Metaprogramming is now constexpr programming.

A second approach is to turn everything into types.

This includes non-type template parameters of templates.

```
template<class T, class N>
using array=std::array<T,N{}()>;

template<auto x>
using k=std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>;
```

now we can pass `k<77>` as a type representing the non-type template parameter `77` to `array<int,k<77>>` and get `std::array<int,77>`.

The type-only array template is now easy to metaprogram with.  Just write those wrappers once, and metaprogram away.

Passing templates around can then be:

```
template<template<class...>class> struct Z{};
```

now we can pass `Z<array>` as a type.