# Can C++ template template parameters accept templates that take non-type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20, template-templates

I have a function like this to implement [`fmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137359/1505451) for C++:

```cpp
// Given a mapping F from T to U and a container of T, return a container of U
// whose elements are created by the mapping from the original container's
// elements.
template <typename F, template <typename...> typename Container, typename T>
Container<std::invoke_result_t<F&, const T&>> Fmap(F&& f,
                                                   const Container<T>& input);
```

The idea is to use a template template parameter (`Container`) to allow accepting any STL-like container. All of the ones in the actual STL I've tried work fine, but a custom container in our codebase doesn't work because it accepts a non-type template parameter

```cpp
template <typename Key, int Foo = 256>
class MyContainer;
```

This causes a substitution failure from clang:

```
template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
```

**Is there a way to abstract over *all* template parameters, not just types?** If not, is there a better way to structure my code to allow doing what I want without specializing for `MyContainer` and all others like it in particular?

Comment: No, there is no way to take any template.

Comment: You don't need to specialise, you only need an alias like `template <typename X> using MyContainerDefault =  MyContainer<X>;` and use `MyContainerDefault` to pass to `Fmap`. Having said that, there is a reason why the standard library algorithms do not accept or return containers, and that reason is *good*.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks; do you think you could expand on both those points in an answer?

Answer (score 3):

A template template parameter can only match one kind of template; that kind is determined by the template parameter list. You have to write another version of `Fmap` if you want to accept `MyContainer`. However, if you do, you can match any template that has one type parameter followed by any number of non-type parameters: it could be an `int` like in your example, or it could be a `char` and a `bool`...

```
template <typename F, template <typename, auto...> typename Container, typename T, auto ...Vs>
Container<std::invoke_result_t<F&, const T&>, Vs...> Fmap(F&& f, const Container<T, Vs...>& input) {
    return {};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5qqn6MnWq)

Comment: Thanks, the `auto` syntax completes part of the puzzle for me. My hope was that there is a syntax I can use to say "any template parameter, type or non-type". I guess that doesn't exist? I would hate to have to write separate overloads for one type parameter followed by non-type parameter, and two, and three, and... Not to mention the fact that they could be interleaved.

Comment: I'm not sure if a "type-or-non-type parameter" syntax could even exist, I assume it would cause some issues with matching.

Comment: @jacobsa One thing you could try (but it's probably not worth the effort) is to change your container template by turning non-type parameters into type parameters. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54156647/3854570) ("second approach") for details.

Comment: @jacobsa Sadly "any template parameter, type or non-type" is not on the menu. Maybe in C++29.

Comment: @Nelfeal, I guess it's not just "type-or-non-type", but "type-or-non-type-or-template".

Answer (score 0):

Since your function does not know the kind of template parameters of the template template parameter, and cannot use them, they all must have defaults in the actual template argument. You can exploit this fact by creating and using an alias template:

```
template <typename F, template <typename /* no pack */> typename Container, typename T>
Container<std::invoke_result_t<F&, const T&>> Fmap(F&& f,
                                                   const Container<T>& input);

template <typename X> using MyContainerDefault =  MyContainer<X>;

something = Fmap(someFunction, MyContainerDefault);
```

Having said that, there is a good reason why standard library algorithms do not accept or return containers. There are many resources that explain this, just search for `why stl algorithms do not work with containers`.

Another point worth mentioning is that in Haskell each "container" (functor) implements `fmap` in its own way, so one general implementation of `Fmap` is rather dubious. If you want to clone `fmap`, it should have an overload for each container or be a container's member function. Once you accept this, you no longer need the template template parameter because each container knows its own template parameters.

Comment: I don't think I understand the purpose of `MyContainerDefault`. Are you saying that callers need to explicitly specify that? The users shouldn't need to know about it. Anyway I am coming around to the idea that there should be a separate specialization per container, like you said; perhaps I'm being too fancy.

Answer (score 0):

To add up to the general suggestion that was already given (*overload for each container*), I think you'd get quite a good overview of *one way* that thing can be accomplished by exploring how [Louis Dionne](https://github.com/ldionne)'s [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) defines [`Functor`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_functor.html) and other concepts (yeah, there are also [`Applicative`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_applicative.html), [`Monad`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_monad.html), [`Comonad`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_comonad.html) and others), and how types like [`boost::hana::basic_tuple`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/b8049374b11398dc9f1b0366f754e69cacc90b46/include/boost/hana/basic_tuple.hpp#L144) or [`boost::hana::optional` (a compile-time optional) implement it](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/b8049374b11398dc9f1b0366f754e69cacc90b46/include/boost/hana/optional.hpp#L241). The interesting part to read with respect to your question is probably [tag dispatching](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-core-tag_dispatching). [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/qza5Ejv8P) is a complete example of how to make `std::array` a `hana::Functor`, so that you can apply [`hana::transform`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Functor.html#ga5a8975f6e55375d5b6038a9c36ee63e7) on it.

Another interesting reading that could broaden your view on this topic, is [P1895](https://wg21.link/p1895), which is also linked off [a post](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/12/01/tag-invoke/) by [Barry Revzin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) on the topic (not exactly in favour of the `tag_invoke` approach that the linked proposal is about).

Some time ago, [I also asked a question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640158/could-stdfootransform-one-day-support-any-functor), but I haven't received a satisfying answer yet.